# MongoDB filter on fields in objects in arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents with the following structure (I am including only two documents here). All documents include `field1` and `array1`. And while the number of objects inside `array1`differs between documents, `field_1` and `field_2` always exist in the objects.

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "field1": "A",
  "array1": {
    "object1": {
      "field_1": "true",
      "field_2": "test"
    },
    "object2": {
      "field_1": "false",
      "field_2": "test"
    }
  }
}

{
  "_id": "2",
  "field1": "A",
  "array1": {
    "object1": {
      "field_1": "true",
      "field_2": "test"
    },
    "object2": {
      "field_1": "true",
      "field_2": "test"
    },
    "object3": {
      "field_1": "false",
      "field_2": "test"
    }
  }
}

{
  "_id": "3",
  "field1": "B",
  "array1": {
    "object1": {
      "field_1": "true",
      "field_2": "test"
    },
    "object2": {
      "field_1": "false",
      "field_2": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to make a query that, for each document where `field1 = "A"`, returns only `field1` and the count of objects in `array1` where the boolean `field_1` is `true`. (There are many more fields and arrays in the document apart from those included here, so it is important that I only retrieve the specified field and array and not everything). So in this example, I would end up with the following:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "field1": "A",
  "array1": "1"
}

{
  "_id": "2",
  "field1": "A",
  "array1": "2"
}
```

I have been testing this query below but don't understand where it goes wrong. I can see however that the count always equals zero, so something is wrong.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "field1": "A" }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "array1": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$array1",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.v.field_1", "true"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Is type of `array1` field is an array ?

Comment: Yes. Type of array1 field is array, and object fields are objects.

Comment: You should've given actual document, as in the given state of this question `array1` doesn't seem like an array rather it seems to an `object` also this `object1` thing is also confusing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to update is this `{ "$eq": ["$$this.v.field_1", "true"] }` to { `"$eq": ["$$this.field_1", "true"] }`, there is not such thing called field `v` inside array field `array1` , Also change to `$project` instead of `$addFields` to just include `field1`, `_id` & `array1` in output. Try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: { field1: 'A' } }, {
    $project: {
        field1: 1, array1: {
            $size: {
                $filter: {
                    "input": "$array1",
                    "as": 'each',
                    "cond": { "$eq": ["$$each.field_1", "true"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Comment: This gives me an output that looks correct at first, but there are only zeroes in the output for the field "array1". So something must be missing.

Comment: @CHRD : Can you give me actual document rather than the JSON that was manually formed .. Does that document look like this `{
    "_id" : "1",
    "field1" : "A",
    "array1" : [ 
        {
            "field_1" : "true",
            "field_2" : "test"
        }, 
        {
            "field_1" : "false",
            "field_2" : "test"
        }
    ]
}` ??

Comment: The actual document is very messy so I am trying to keep it tidy..

Comment: It seems to work when I drop the quotations around "true"

Comment: @CHRD :: Ok field types should match, if you've a boolean then `"cond": { "$eq": ["$$each.field_1", true] }` or if it's string :: `'true'` then `"cond": { "$eq": ["$$each.field_1", "true"] }` or if it's string :: `'True'` then it should be `"cond": { "$eq": ["$$each.field_1", "True"] }`

Comment: Thank you. I do have a boolean as stated in the question. So dropping the quotation works out.